# Optimization problem with constraint is another optimization problem

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I would like to know how to solve a problem like this:
$$\min f(x) s.t.\; g(x)\leq 0$$.
However, we do not have explicit form of $g(x)$. What we know is that $g(x)$ is another solution of an optimization problem, say $g(x)=\inf_{\beta} h(x,\beta)$. Here, $h(x,\beta)$ is known, but assuming that we cannot solve the optimization analytically. I would like to know what kind of such optimization called and ways to solve this kind of problem.

Comment: Denote $z=(x,\beta)$ and definte $F(z)=f(x)$. Then your problem is basically $\min_z F(z)$ subject to $h(z)\le 0$.

Comment: These are called "bilevel optimization problems."   There's quite a bit of literature on them.